# Bad Request (400) after requesting additional rights with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have also posted this question at: "http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=243598"

In our application, we want to request rights in different stages. First, at login, I request "read_stream" rights, and later when a user selects that he/she want to receive e-mail notifications, I want to request additional "email" rights.

The first request works fine:

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Perms = "read_stream")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home"); // Logged in
    }
```

In a later scenario, I try to do the same in another controller action to request additional email permissions:

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Perms = "email")]
    public ActionResult NotifyMe()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
```

This time however, when the redirect comes back from Facebook, I get a Bad Request 400 error. The URL looks like this:
"http://localhost:84/facebookredirect.axd//amiinterestingdev/NotAllowed/NotifyMe?perms=email&selected_profiles=609505986&session=%7B%22session_key%22%3A%222.Ss4aOQFlkIhSjPZT1ICtSw__.3600.1296169200-609505986%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22609505986%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1296169200%2C%22secret%22%3A%22JO6vtN6OuL7WXt1c_RkXCA__%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22148210175210859%7C2.Ss4aOQFlkIhSjPZT1ICtSw__.3600.1296169200-609505986%7CihpYs9tHc23..."

If I remove one of the double forward slashed right after facebookredirect.axd it works.

Does anyone know how to fix this or workaround the bug if it is a bug?

Thank you in advance!

// Peter

Answer (score 0):

Do you have :

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler" />
</handlers>
```

defined in your web.config ?